# libnet sending RST packets

Tags: c, linux, libnet

I was just trying out the [code snippet here](https://github.com/sam-github/libnet/blob/master/libnet/sample/synflood.c) for fun and learning. I did a wireshark capture on the interface and noticed something strange.

The `SYN` packets were sent out as expected and I seem to be receiving `SYN ACK`s in response. I have a sleep of about 5 seconds each after sending each SYN packet. I notice that my machine sends a `RST` packet to the server after receiving each `SYN ACK` even though there is no code for the same. Why does that happen and how could I prevent that from happening?

Comment: I'd assume your kernel handles the SYN/ACK replies. Since there never was a respective SYN packet sent and the reply is unwanted, the kernel sends back a RST reply. This is one of the reasons to spoof the IP address performing a SYN flood - if you don't, you degrade your link as well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but on searching a bit many said about adding a filter in the firewall, there by not allowing the kernel to send the RST packet.So looked into unix command `iptables`, where on `OUTPUT` chain you can apply a filter saying going to a specific dst with tcp protocol and RST flag set drop it. Command being:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <dst-ip> --tcp-flag SYN,RST RST -j DROP
```